# Autoscrolling after page refresh doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, page-refresh

I'm trying to do automatic scrolling to the left side of my horizontal website after refresh (like pressing F5). I was trying `scrollLeft()` and got nothing. Now `window.scrollTo(0,0)` is working but just with a button like this:

```
 function scrollWindow()
 {
 window.scrollTo(0,0); 
 }
```

and

```
<input type="button" onclick="scrollWindow()" value="Scroll" />
```

This works, but doesn't with `$(document).ready(function());`:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(scrollWindow());
</script>
```

I found in another question top answer:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

But it didn't work for me. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    scrollWindow();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(scrollWindow());`

You execute `scrollWindow` function before the document is ready. It invokes immediately after script initialisation. That is why it is not working. I can just modify @Eli answer and suggest to use the next function:

```
$(document).ready(scrollWindow);
```

Comment: It's still not working, and button for scroll is working. Maybe i have this script in wrong place, when should I put it?

Comment: If script with `scrollWindow` function is defined in another file it should be included before the script with document ready function

Comment: It is like this in head section:

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="scrolling.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(scrollWindow);
</script>